# Connection Issues when using AcquireTokenAsync() in Xamarin Forms Windows App with Azure AD B2C and custom policy

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL to connect my Xamarin.Forms-Windows 8.1-App to Azure AD B2C with a custom SignInSignUp-policy (to login the user by using a custom E-Mail address and a password). The "normal" authentication against Azure AD (without custom policy) works fine, but when I use the policy, the message "We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later." appears everytime after providing the credentials (directly within the dialog). Since the dialog does not finish correctly, I am not retrieving any exception or AuthenticationResult and so I am not able to determine the concrete issue (the internet connection itself is not the problem).

Note: I also tried this in a Xamarin.Forms-UWP-App which leads me to the same issue. Under iOS, it is working fine and the dialog finishes and closes correctly.

NuGet Versions:
MSAL (Microsoft.Identity.Client): 1.0.304142201-alpha
Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.2.118-pre1

Thats my code (simplified):

```
var clientId = "{My application's ClientId}";
var redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{My Azure AD B2C}";
string[] scopes = { clientId };
var policy = "{My SignUpSignIn policy}";

var clientApplication = new PublicClientApplication (authority, clientId);
clientApplication.RedirectUri = redirectUri;

var result = await this.clientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, string.Empty, UiOptions.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, authority, policy);
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turns out I forgot to properly set up my mobile app to allow loggin in via Active Directory

The steps I took that solved my problem were:

1. In Azure B2C Blade select Application and set the Reply URL to the address of the Azure Mobile Apps instance (e.g. https://myapp.azurewebsites.net), followed by /.auth/login/aad/callback
2. Make sure the policies used in the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant should be configured so that the Reply URL is set to the same as above
3. In the Azure Mobile or Services App go to settings-->authentication/autorization and make sure that a non authenticated request is set up to log in with AAD
4. in the same blade select the AAD provider, go to advanced and set up Client ID and Issuer URL, with the Client ID being the Application ID of the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant, and the Issuer Url being the Metadata Endpoint for the Azure Active Directory B2C policy

Once I did the above all worked flawlessly.
More detailed instructions can be found at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app/

Let me know if this helped...